# Express a boolean formula using only $\to$

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

To express $F$ using only $\to$ for

$$F = \overline{A \lor B} = \overline{\overline{A} \to B}$$

but you only need to use $\to$. I do not know how to get rid of negation.

Comment: Why do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need something like $\bot$ (tye constant that is always *false*) to write:

> $¬A =_{def} A \to \bot$.

In [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) we have the constants $0$ and $1$.

We have:

> $x \to y= \overline x \lor y$.

Thus:

> > $x \to 0 = \overline x \lor 0 = \overline x$.

Comment: Seeing as the question is about representing $\bot$, saying that you can do it if you have $\bot$ seems underwhelming...